# Ensuring Polynomials in array have same degree

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, linear-algebra

So, I'm currently coding an question from an old linear algebra homework. I have three polynomials of degree 2, and I am transforming them into polynomials of degree 2.
Each polynomial *p* is of the form: `a0 + a1x + a2x^2`

These are my polynomials:
`(1 - x + 0x^2, 1 + 2x + 0x^2, 0 + 0x + 0x^2)`
Here they are represented in code. I am using numpy.polynomial.Polynomial:

```
basis_b = np.array([[Polynomial([1, -1, 0])], 
                    [Polynomial([1, 2, 0])], 
                    [Polynomial([0, 0, 1])]
                   ])
```

With the transformation:
`p'(2 - x) + 3*p`
Represented in code as:

```
def trans_t(basis: np.array):
    return np.array([polynomial.polyadd(
                        polynomial.polymul(poly[0].deriv(), Polynomial([2, -1, 0])),
                        polynomial.polymul(Polynomial([3, 0, 0]), poly[0])) 
                    for poly in basis])
```

Originally, I was using python arithmetic in the function, but I switched to polynomial arithmetic in an attempt to solve the problem; it did not work.

So, I am receiving the correct answer when applying my transformation. However, the code returns polynomials of degree 1 even though the polynomials are of degree 2.

Here is my output upon calling the function:

```
change_of_basis(basis_b, basis_b, trans_t)
```

```
change_of_basis(basis_b, basis_b, trans_t)

array([[Polynomial([ 1., -2.], domain=[-1.,  1.], window=[-1.,  1.])],
       [Polynomial([7., 4.], domain=[-1.,  1.], window=[-1.,  1.])],
       [Polynomial([0., 4., 1.], domain=[-1.,  1.], window=[-1.,  1.])]],
      dtype=object)
```

What would be the numpy way of ensuring that I have a 0 coefficient for x^2 if there is no coefficient for x^2 when applying the function such that it returns

```
Polynomial([1, -2, 0])
Polynomial([7, 4, 0])
```

Comment: the polynomial in basis_b are not all of degree 2. Only the last one is.

Comment: If you want fast operations with numpy, use a 2D array of coefficients, not Polynomial objects.

Comment: The last polynomial should have `1x^2`. The actual degree of your first two polynomials is indeed one, not two. You have an implicit `0x^3` throughout, but we don't talk about that as a degree any more than `0x^2`

Answer (score 0):

Here are your polynomials

```
1 - 1x + 0x^2
1 + 2x + 0x^2
0 + 0x + 1x^2
```

It's much faster to represent them as a matrix than to work with `Polynomial` objects, since at that point you are foregoing virtually all the benefits of numpy and treating your basis as a list of python objects.

The matrix will not reduce your dimensions unless you tell it to:

```
p = np.array([
    [1, -1, 0],
    [1,  2, 0],
    [0,  0, 1]])
```

Rows represent polynomials and columns represent coefficients. First let's define a column of zeros that we'll use a lot later:

```
pad = np.zeros((p.shape[0], 1))
```

The derivative can be computed fairly simply in a number of ways:

```
d = p[:, 1:] * np.arange(1, p.shape[1])
```

You can preserve the degree by appending the pad:

```
d_full = np.hstack((p[:, 1:] * np.arange(1, p.shape[1]), pad))
```

Multiplying by `(2 - x)` brings the degree back up:

```
t = np.hstack((pad, d * 2)) - np.hstack((d, pad)) + p * 3
```

Or alternatively:

```
t = d_full * 2 - np.roll(d_full, -1, axis=1) + p * 3
```

You can transform the result `t` into an array of `Polynomial` objects if you wish.